# Web-scraping using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to catch some info about amazon stuff. Idk why my code doesn't work. Every time i try to test these lines, i get a None output.
I'm using visual studio.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://www.amazon.it/Xiaomi-frequenza-Monitoraggio-Bracciale-Smartwatch/dp/B07T9DHKXL?pf_rd_r=F2MMPNCJR5AQ4KP5C82P&pf_rd_p=ff59f7ef-650d-5e5a-9ee5-6fd80bb0e21d&pd_rd_r=12e6add2-54cd-44b1-bfa4-81c70ad68010&pd_rd_w=Lo5MD&pd_rd_wg=t2rFz&ref_=pd_gw_ri"
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
title = soup.find(id='productTitle')
price = soup.find(id='priceblock_ourprice')
print(title)
print(price)
```

Comment: did you try checking `soup` value? does it have these elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

1.) Use HTTP header `User-Agent`. Without it, Amazon sends you CAPTCHA page.

2.) As parser select `html5lib` or `lxml`. `html.parser` has problems parsing this page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.amazon.it/Xiaomi-frequenza-Monitoraggio-Bracciale-Smartwatch/dp/B07T9DHKXL'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html5lib') # or 'lxml'

title = soup.find(id='productTitle')
price = soup.find(id='priceblock_ourprice')
print(title.get_text(strip=True))
print(price.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
Xiaomi Mi Band 4 Activity Tracker,Monitor attività,Monitor frequenza cardiaca Monitoraggio Fitness, Bracciale Smartwatch con Schermo AMOLED a Colori 0,95, con iOS e Android (Versione Globale)
30,96 €
```

Comment: ty man, i had to install lmxl  using sudo pip3 install lxml, then it worked

Answer (score 1):

Andrej Kesely gave you the answer while I was typing, but to understand why this happens,

just add this print line after the soup = ... :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all("title"))
title = soup.find(id='productTitle')
```

This will print:

```
[<title dir="ltr">Amazon CAPTCHA</title>]
```

Amazon isn't "showing" the real page to your code, it is asking for a captcha.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern websites including Amazon load webpages dynamically using javascript. When you send a request using `requests.get` you get only the initial render of the webpage without the dynamically loaded content. You could use a library like `selenium` to load dynamically loaded webpages and then parse the page source to beautiful soup.